# NS-3 Simulation takes too long

Tags: python, ubuntu, wifi, ns-3, waf

I'm using Ubuntu 16.40 with 4GB of RAM.

```
./waf --pyrun wifi-olsr-flowmonitor.py
```

When I run the `wifi-olsr-flowmonitor.py` file in NS-3 for 9 nodes, it took 17 hours to complete the simulation. Why did it take that long? And what can I do to prevent this from hapenning again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. It's because I wrote my terminal output to a text file. So it took much more time when the delay increases time to time.